# View for individual user groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, list-view, groups

I have two user groups. One of them (admini_folder) is a group containing administrators, which has all available permissions. The second group is (Baza_danych_test) is a group that has display only permissions - they can't edit anything.
[image]

I have different lists in the site content. I would like to create two views in one list - one with all the elements visible for people who are in the administrators group and the other for people from the other group.

I know how to hide records for a "normal" user - in the end the end user will see something like the one shown on the screen below. I used a simple filter for the elements.
[image]

The admin group should see all the items in the list - as shown in the example screen below.
[image]

When I create an administrator's view, I create it for myself. How can I share a view with a specific group of people? For example, administrators in "admini_folders" group should see the view created by me. In this view's settings I can't find the assignment of a particular group to this view. **How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is **No** way to use target Audience in SharePoint Modern List view.

**Workaround**:

1. Go to your SharePoint list.
2. Click on **Return to classic SharePoint** (You can find it below left side navigation - bottom left corner of the page).
3. Click on **Settings** (Gear icon) --> **Edit page**.
4. Then **Edit Web Part**.
5. In web part properties panel, expand **Advanced** section.
6. Inside **Target Audiences** add your administrators group (admini_folder).
7. Click **OK**.
8. Click on **PAGE** from top ribbon --> Select **Stop Editing**.
9. Click on **Exit classic experience** (You can find it below left side navigation - bottom left corner of the page).

**References**:

1. Check **Target web parts to an audience** at: [How does Audience Targeting in a List / Document Library work?](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-does-audience-targeting-in-a-list-document-library-work/)
2. Check **Web Parts** topic on Page 4 at: [Audience Targeting in SharePoint](https://www.combined-knowledge.com/documents/knowledgebase/Audience%20Targeting%20in%20SharePoint.pdf).