# limit a user to see specific view of a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, audience-targeting

How can I grant permission to a user to only see a specific view of a SharePoint list and not "All Items", I cannot find any related settings in "Permissions for this list".

This solution here [View for individual user groups](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276364/view-for-individual-user-groups/276372#276372) seems exactly what I need.

I am not sure why I can not see Mohs Sich in the list of the target audience, I have tested all the three options: Please note this user is an external user.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using classic experience of modern experience? To set the permissions on particular view you need to use Target Audience. Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276364/view-for-individual-user-groups/276372#276372) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250560/limiting-permission-on-all-items-and-views/250570#250570).

Comment: Thanks it looks like exactly what I am looking for, just a point, added two photos

Comment: Sorry...Where have you added photos?

Comment: added photos, thanks

Comment: Thank you. Added my answer below. please upvote and accept it as an answer. keep using this platform to ask your doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is **No** way to use target Audience in SharePoint Modern List view.

**Workaround**:

1. Go to your SharePoint list.
2. Click on **Return to classic SharePoint** (You can find it below left side navigation - bottom left corner of the page).
3. Click on **Settings** (Gear icon) --> **Edit page**.
4. Then select the list web part & then **Edit Web Part**.
5. In web part properties panel, expand **Advanced** section, it is on the most right corner of the page next to the list (you may need to scroll horizontally, as shown below).
6. Inside **Target Audiences** add your administrators group (admini_folder).
7. Click **OK**.
8. Click on **PAGE** from top ribbon --> Select **Stop Editing**.
9. Click on **Exit classic experience** (You can find it below left side navigation - bottom left corner of the page).

This only works for groups, so you need to add your user to a group.

[image]
**References**:

1. Check **Target web parts to an audience** at: [How does Audience Targeting in a List / Document Library work?](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-does-audience-targeting-in-a-list-document-library-work/)
2. Check **Web Parts** topic on Page 4 at: [Audience Targeting in SharePoint](https://www.combined-knowledge.com/documents/knowledgebase/Audience%20Targeting%20in%20SharePoint.pdf).

Comment: thx a lot again

Comment: @Ganesh, I am not sure what set-up this is for, but your instructions fail at step 2 in the modern experience as there is no "return to classic experience" option. Also you add target audience sections in the page menu from the site contents screen.

Comment: @RobertW081171 - I'm not seeing this. I know you can add Audience Targeting to the List Settings' Audience Targeting" menu but that only enables an item-level audience targeting using a new column.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ganesh answer (Which I really appreciate that), I also found another way to automate this in Power Automate (MS Flow) as mentioned in this post (Thanks to Chelsea and Rohit):

[Is there a way to stop editing an item when the approval status is pending in SP online list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286885/is-there-a-way-to-stop-editing-an-item-when-the-approval-status-is-pending-in-sp)