# SPO List Views - Audience Targeting Substitute

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, audience-targeting

I'm told by our SP Admin team that Audience Targeting in SPO Modern Experience is not (yet) available. I need ideas for a work-around or substitute approaches in several lists where:

Example #1: List Views are named for Regions and viewership is filtered by people in each Region. I need to keep users from wandering outside their Region's data, including the AllItems view.

Example #2: In a list, users enter nominations. The nominator should only see their own entries. Admins should see all nominations.

--> Would your ideas be dependent on a stand-alone SPO site/list or a Teams-Initiated site/list?

Thanks-

Comment: Try this once and see if it works: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277474/limit-a-user-to-see-specific-view-of-a-sharepoint-list/277477#277477. Else you will have to run a power automate flow on item creation/update, break list item permissions and then grant permissions to groups based on region selection.